# Best method to deal with numbers? Getting and changing individual digits

Tags: performance, math, numbers

I want to take a 1 to 17 digit number, then put it through a series of logic loops that will change various digits of the number. I need to be able to do the following:

1) A quick way to know how many digits there are in the number. Is there a good (efficient) php method to do this? Is getting log base 10 the best way? Or maybe turning it into a string and asking for the length?

2) Next, I need to know what number is in each digit. Should I just keep doing % 10 on the number to parse each digit (doing this would also help solve problem number 1 by adding a count in the loop)?

3) Finally, I need a good way to change the various digits of the number. Should I use regex? Or should I just build up a new number by adding various numbers together, with each number representing the digit (ex. 1 + 30 + 400 + 2000 + 6000 = 62431)? I guess I could also adjust the original number in the same method as the last example by adding/subtracting from it to adjust each digit to the one I want.

Please let me know about other ways to solve my problem if you feel they're faster. Efficiency is key.

Comment: Since you already have some ideas for 1 & 2, why not try benchmarking them yourself?

Comment: I'm actually not that proficient in benchmarking (basically have no clue). Are there any good tools to do so in php? Or should I just output the timestamp after like a million loops? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Check my post for a simple benchmarking example. I've already checked the number length methods. Using the common log is 3 times faster then string casting and substr.

Comment: If you want this to be at all reliable, you need to use strings.

Comment: To get the length of an integer `i`, a quick way (in C) is: `n=1; if(i>=100000000){n+=8;i/=100000000;} if(i>=10000){n+=4;i/=10000;} if(i>=100){n+=2;i/=100} if(i>=10){n+=1;}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change the value of a digit in a number with something like the following:

```
function numlen($number) { return strlen($number); }

function numAt($number, $index) { return substr($number, $index, 1); }

function changeNumAt($number, $index, $newDigit) {
    return substr_replace($number, $newDigit, $index, 1);
}
```

For your situation, using the number as a string for a one time number change makes the most sense. To save time, if you will be changing multiple digits you should parse the number into an array of digits. Let me know in the comments if you would like help with doing this.

---

Simple Benchmarking example:

```
$start = microtime(true); //Log the start timestamp (including microseconds)
//Do stuff to benchmark
$end = microtime(true); //Log the end timestamp (including microseconds)
echo ((string)($end-$start))."seconds \n";
```

Use `microtime(true)` to get the timestamp with microseconds as a float (that's what the true is for). Get the time before and after the action and subtract them to get the total time.

Comment: Your code examples are not going to work with standard floating-point numbers.

Comment: I don't see why not. The using the common log for the length will work (since decimals don't need to be counted). `numAt()` will work for numbers before the decimal. And `changeNumAt()` will work for changing values before the decimal. The only thing you can't do is change numbers after the decimal (I can modify my code for this if the OP needs it).

Comment: It won't work because of limited precision of floating-point numbers. Try your code on 1000000000000 and modify it to 1000000000001.

Comment: @quant_dev That is a PHP limitation. And I don't see how one trillion is a standard number unless you are dealing with the US deficit! :P

Comment: No, that's the limitation of 64-bit doubles. You'll have the same problem in Java, C or C++ (unless you use non-standard doubles with extended precision). And the same problem can appear when dealing with 1.1234567890123456. The OP explicitly asked about manipulating digits of numbers with 1 to 17 digits. Given the nature of floating point numbers, the position of the decimal point is irrelevant.

Comment: @quant_dev I've updated my code to avoid the problem as you have suggested. Thanks for pointing this out. I was aware of the problem with floating point integers, but wasn't aware that it applied in this situation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write an answer because the currently accepted one is simply wrong. The relative precision of `double` numbers is of the order of 1E-16. This is not a limitation of PHP, this is an intrinsic feature of IEEE 754 `double`. Hence, if you want to manipulate the 17-th digit of a double number, no matter what the magnitude of the number is, using logs and performing arithmetical operations will not do. What you need to do is to convert the number to the string, manipulate the digits in the string and display it from the string, without converting it back to `double`.